# In mypy, reveal_locals is not defined

Tags: python, mypy

Running mypy on the following file reports the error that `reveal_locals` is not defined:

```
from typing import Iterable

def f(stream: Iterable[str]):
    for val in stream:
        reveal_locals()
```

I'm running Windows 10 with Python 3.6.4 and mypy 0.580. The actual error I see on the console is

```
$ python -m mypy file.py
file.py:5: error: Name 'reveal_locals' is not defined
```

Am I using a wrong python version or am I missing something? My interpretation of [the documentation](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html) seems to indicate that I'm doing what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Can you check which version of mypy you're using? `reveal_locals` was only added [about a month ago](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2018/06/mypy-0610-released.html) in mypy 0.610 – check that you're running at least that version.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. The version I was using was 0.580. I've now updated and the problem is no more. If you make that an answer I'll be sure to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reveal_locals` was only added in mypy 0.610 (released [about a month ago](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2018/06/mypy-0610-released.html)); check that you're running the most recent version.